# Combining Local business with Service & Area served schema

Tags: schema, json-ld

When I insert this code in the structured data testing tool I am only getting the first schema to show up. I can switch the order of the Local business and service w/ area served but when I do that only one of them shows up in the tool. The same thing happens when I try to split the two up and get them individually.

Working with json-ld scripts:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "ProfessionalService",
  "name": "Sebastian River Exterminating",
  "image": "http://sebastianriverexterminating.com/images/extermination-logo-sebastian-fl.png",
  "@id": "",
  "url": "http://sebastianriverexterminating.com/",
  "telephone": "7722289969",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "124 Salazar Lane",
    "addressLocality": "Sebastian",
    "addressRegion": "FL",
    "postalCode": "32958",
    "addressCountry": "US"
  },
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": 27.7600115,
    "longitude": -80.50620599999999
  },
  "openingHoursSpecification": {
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
    "dayOfWeek": [
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday"
    ],
    "opens": "08:00",
    "closes": "18:00"
  },
  "sameAs": "https://www.facebook.com/SebastianRiverExterminatingFL/timeline"
}
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Service",
    "serviceType": "Exterminator",
    "additionalType": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pest_control",
    "areaServed": [
        {
            "@type": "City",
            "name": "Sebastian",
            "@id": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebastian,_Florida"
        },
        {
            "@type": "City",
            "name": "Roseland",
            "@id": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roseland,_Florida"
        }
    ]}
</script>
```

Comment: If you wrap them in 2 separate ```<script>``` tags, google testing tool (https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) seems to accept it. Also, note that seems to be deprecated, according to the description text (see here: https://schema.org/ProfessionalService).

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid json or json-ld. You can only add one object to each script. e.g.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
...
}
</script>
```

You can't list objects like you did.

One way around the issue is to add each into their own script tag.

Another is to use @graph to add them as an array inside an object. e.g.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@graph": [
    {
      ...
    }, 
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use a sameAs not an @id in this case, since you are providing a reference for the search engine.  also, I don't believe @id is a valid property of areaServed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).